# Как вытащить текст из textarea ?

Tags: html, javascript

Как вытащить текст из `<textarea></textarea>`? Сначала собирался так `<textarea onkeypress='alert(this.innerHTML)'></textarea>` - не пашет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.value
```

Comment: а разве в <textarea></textarea> текст хранится не между тегов?

Comment: Именно там, но тут дело в том, что TEXTAREA для браузера - такое же текстовое поле, как например INPUT TEXT. Следовательно, текст в нем хранится схожим образом.